# How to save the scraped results into a CSV file from multiple website pages?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape some ASINs(lets say 600 ASINs) from amazon website(just the ASINs) with selenium and beautifulsoup.My main issue is how to save all the scraped data into a CSV file ? I've tried something but it only saves the last scraped page.

Here is the code:

```
from time import sleep
import requests
import time
import json
import re
import sys
import numpy as np
from selenium import webdriver
import urllib.request
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen


i = 1
while(True):
    try:
        if i == 1:
            url = "https://www.amazon.es/s?k=doll&i=toys&rh=n%3A599385031&dc&page=1"
        else:
            url = "https://www.amazon.es/s?k=doll&i=toys&rh=n%3A599385031&dc&page={}".format(i)
        r = requests.get(url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

        #print page url
        print(url)

        #rest of the scraping code
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get(url)

        HTML = driver.page_source
        HTML1=driver.page_source
        soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML1, "html.parser")
        styles = soup.find_all(name="div", attrs={"data-asin":True})
        res1 = [i.attrs["data-asin"] for i in soup.find_all("div") if i.has_attr("data-asin")]
        print(res1)
        data_record.append(res1)
        #driver.close()

        #don't overflow website
        sleep(1)

        #increase page number
        i += 1
        if i == 3:
            print("STOP!!!")
            break
    except:
        break
```

Comment: you just need to check if your `print (res1)`  has the asin values you need, then store them in a csv file. Are you trying replicate what this site does: https://asintool.com/?

Comment: print(res1) gives the ASINs from the page number 1 then show the ASINs from page number 2. I just want to save ALL Asins from the scraped pages.

Comment: Yes i want to retrieve the ASINs from a specific keyword.

Comment: okay, start by creating an empty dataframe before the loop like `df = pd.DataFrame([])` and then add this in the loop: `df = df.append(res1)` then export dataframe to csv like this : `df.to_csv`. let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing items that do not seem to be used at the moment a possible solution could be

```
import csv
import bs4
import requests
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep


def retrieve_asin_from(base_url, idx):
    url = base_url.format(idx)
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')

    with webdriver.Chrome() as driver:
        driver.get(url)
        HTML1 = driver.page_source
        soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(HTML1, "html.parser")
        res1 = [i.attrs["data-asin"]
                for i in soup.find_all("div") if i.has_attr("data-asin")]
    sleep(1)
    return res1


url = "https://www.amazon.es/s?k=doll&i=toys&rh=n%3A599385031&dc&page={}"
data_record = [retrieve_asin_from(url, i) for i in range(1, 4)]

combined_data_record = combine_records(data_record) # fcn to write

with open('asin_data.csv', 'w', newline='') as fd:
    csvfile = csv.writer(fd)
    csvfile.writerows(combined_data_record)
```

Comment: You made it look so simple :) It works, but what should i adjust so data can be in the same column ?

Comment: You could add a fucntion - returning a new array - for `data_record` in which you combine the necessary fields.  The new array can then be used when you write the csv file.